# What is the name of the design pattern where I dynamically pick the correct implementation based on data?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, cdi, software-design

Originally I picked the correct User implementation, based on domain and realm data from the Java EE server. However that was company code, so I had to rewrite the example with numbers. I hope the underlying pattern is still understandable though. For those unfamiliar with CDI, @Inject Instance allows you to iterate through all implementations of an interface.

```
public class NumberPicker {

    @Inject
    private Instance<NumberMapper> mappers;

    public Number parse (String string) {
        for( NumberMapper mapper : mappers ){
            if( mapper.isApplicable(string) ){
                return mapper.apply(string);
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Can not parse " + string);
    }

}

public interface NumberMapper {

    boolean isApplicable (String string);

    Number apply (String string);

}

public class ByteMapper implements NumberMapper {

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable (String string) {
        return string.length() == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Number apply (String string) {
        return (byte) string.charAt(0);
    }

}

public class IntegerMapper implements NumberMapper {

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable (String string) {
        if( string.length() == 1 ){
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(string);
            return true;
        }catch( NumberFormatException e ){
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Number apply (String string) {
        return Integer.parseInt(string);
    }

}

public class FloatMapper implements NumberMapper

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable (String string) {
        if( string.length() == 1 ) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(string);
            return false;
        }catch( NumberFormatException e){
        }
        try {
            Float.parseFloat(string);
            return true;
        }catch( NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Number apply (String string) {
        return Float.parseFloat(string);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the **Strategy Pattern**:

```
public interface Strategy {
   boolean test();
   void execute();
}

public class FirstStrategy implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public boolean test() {
      //returns true or false
   }

   @Override
   public void execute() {
       //your custom implementation
   }
}


public class SecondStrategy implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public boolean test() {
      //returns true or false
   }

   @Override
   public void execute() {
       //your custom implementation
   }
}
```

Then you have your list of strategies:

```
List<Strategy> strategiesList = List.of(new FirstStrategy(), new SecondStrategy());
```

Thus:

```
strategiesList.stream()
    .filter(aStrategy -> aStrategy.test())
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(aStrategy -> aStrategy.execute());
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the strategy pattern? I have checked a lot of sites on strategy pattern, and the patterns do not match perfectly. Strategy pattern seems to be simply the interface override with multiple implementations. This might be something more, with a dynamic picker attached.

Comment: The "dynamic selector" you are talking about is the filter stage of the stream: `aStrategy.test()`. The stream checks the strategies you have in the `strategiesList` and when the `test()` method dynamically satisfies your condition, the corresponding execute method is executed automatically. 
So basically you don't know which strategy (ies) will be executed except at runtime.